# Turn off Bootstrap's CSS3 transitions on progress bars

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Anyone know a way to disable Bootstrap's CSS3 transitions on the progress bars?  I'm updating them via javascript/jquery and don't want them doing the animating.

This looked promising but couldn't get it to work: [Turn Off CSS3 Animation With jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9353942/turn-off-css3-animation-with-jquery)

Info on progress bars: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#progress

Comment: Might be stupid, but you can't just edit CSS and remove references to *-transition?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can turn off the transition effects by setting the css `transition` rule to `none`, like so:

```
.progress .bar {
    -webkit-transition: none;
    -moz-transition: none;
    -ms-transition: none;
    -o-transition: none;
    transition: none;
}​
```

Comment: That did it!  Should have been looking for the transition property instead. Thanks!

Comment: Change the CSS selector to just .progress-bar in order to disable the transition effects in Bootstrap 3.0

Comment: I added a new class like `no-transition` with this style marked as `!important` so this way I can selectively turn it off for specific progress bars.

Answer (score 2):

Since the animation is comes from the `active` class you can just use

```
$('.progress').removeClass('active');
```

or

```
$('.progress').toggleClass('active');
```

Comment: This question was more about transition than animation

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it stopping with `$(".progress-bar").stop()` the animation and then start it back again.

I wanted to have the bar back to `0` and start again to move to `100%`. So here how it goes:

```
$(".progress-bar").stop();      //Stopping the current animation at the current width
$(".progress-bar").animate({width: "0%"}, 100);       //Going back to 0% smoothly in 100ms
$(".progress-bar").animate({width: "100%"}, 1000);    //Restarting the process bar to 100%
```

I hope it will help some.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with javascript

```
      $('#proc').hide();
      $("#proc").width(0 + "%");
      $('#proc').show();
```

For me its working fine. Not flashing and just doing its job. You can also do it with pure css I think.