# Unset css animation property with jQuery.css method

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I know that CSS3 `animation` property is removed by setting to `none !important`, and so I tried (and did, within CSS code). But, by using `jQuery.css()` method to change animation property to mentioned, it doesn't work.

I have tried

```
$('#site-title, #site-description').css(
    {
        'animation':'none !important',
        '-webkit-animation':'none !important',
        '-moz-animation':'none !important',
        '-o-animation':'none !important'
    }

);
```

and also tried (knowing that jQuery in many cases handles prefixes automatically )

```
$('#site-title, #site-description').css(
    {
        'animation':'none !important'

    }

);
```

...no good. Just to note, I haven't mess node selection, when I for test purposes inser `display:none` they're gone.

How to resolve this?

Comment: isn't that `$('#site-title, #site-description').css('animation','none !important');` Not sure if the `.css` prototype works with objects.. http://api.jquery.com/css/ (despite using a class is slightly easier there)

Comment: you could try removeClass. This will remove your animation when you dont want it then addClass when you do want it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set like this:

```
function stopAnimation()
{
    $('#site-title, #site-description').css("-webkit-animation", "none");
    $('#site-title, #site-description').css("-moz-animation", "none");
    $('#site-title, #site-description').css("-ms-animation", "none");
    $('#site-title, #site-description').css("animation", "none");
}
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9353942/turn-off-css3-animation-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

try using  a CSS class (note: `!important` could not be necessary anymore)

```
.removeanimation {
    -webkit-animation:none !important;
    -moz-animation:none !important;
    -o-animation: none !important;
    animation:none !important;
}
```

then add the class to your elements

```
$('#site-title, #site-description').addClass('removeanimation');
```

Comment: Logic-wise I think it'd be better the other way around - have a class which adds the animation, then remove that class. This way you're not having to set everything back to `none` and, more importantly, you can drop the `!important` altogether.

Comment: yes, I left the `!important` only because I don't know how much specific is the rule that is activating the animation and I learnt to never make assumptions ;)  but I agree that probably is not necessary (so I've edited the answer)

Comment: This answer is correct, however I have to accept sasi's answer because it is pointing exactly to the strange quirk with jQuery, and reveals how to do it with .css method. Upvote for you, of course.

Comment: @Miloshio fair, just remember that it's always good to keep off css from javascript for less redundancy, better separation of layers and better mantainability of code  so, in the end, whatever answer you accept I strongly suggest this approach

Answer (score 0):

For setting !important with jquery.css you should use this way:

```
$('#elem').css('cssText', 'animation: none !important');
```

[Read More](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655925/how-to-apply-important-using-css)

Comment: `!important` is actually completely redundant here as jQuery's `css()` method modifies the element's `style` attribute, which has the highest specificity.

Comment: I mean the `!important` here is completely unnecessary as it won't affect anything.